# How can I set up the initial route in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

If I set up the initial route in react, there is homepage

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://localhost:3001/admin",
...
```

How about next.js?

Is there solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In nextjs you can use rewrites - https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites

Your rewrite would look something like this.

```
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/admin',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```